# Create a list from instance variables of items in array using streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an array of items, and I want to create a list (or any iterable) from an instance variable belonging to them.

```
public void foo(final MyClass... args) {
    final List<Baz> properties = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final MyClass a : args) {
        properties.add(a.getProperty());
    }
}
```

How would I do this using a one-liner stream?

Comment: So an instance of `MyClass` has a property of type `MyClass`? Am I getting this right?

Comment: `java.util.List` has no `append` method.

Comment: Fixed both, wrote this without compiling it and I jump between programming languages

Comment: `Arrays.stream(args).map(MyClass::getProperty).collect(Colectors.toList());` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Baz> list = Arrays.stream(args).map(MyClass::getProperty).collect(Collectors.toList());
Iterable<Baz> iterable = () -> Arrays.stream(args).map(MyClass::getProperty).iterator();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `getProperty()` method of `MyClass` returns an object of type `Baz`

```
List<Baz> properties = Stream.of(args)
.map(myClazz -> myClazz.getProperty())
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```